# iOS Simulator Loading Upside-Down in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I haven't done anything funky with my code, and am running the latest version of XCode, but for some reason when I run a build on the simulator, everything works perfectly except for the fact that it's upside down. Any idea why that could be the case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try rotating the device?  (not a joke, there is an option to rotate the simulator)

Comment: but the simulator usually starts up straight...might be something else

Comment: are you talking about the simulator or the contents inside it

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your application screen on simulator here. Will Help.

Answer (score 8):

I had (have) this problem also. At first I though I found it when I created a fresh app and compared the Info.plist and discovered my app had the **Supported Device Orientations** different from the fresh app.

Specifically, I had **Portrait Top** above **Portrait Bottom**. After I put the **Portrait Bottom** at the head of the list the problem disappeared.

Or so I thought. I reorganized the main folder and put all the PNG files into a Resources folder. Deleted the old references in the project and add in the new locations and now the problem is back.

Also, noted the problem is occuring on the actual iOS device. You can see in this launch pix the status bar and picture are both upside down. As soon as my mainView loads the view orients correctly and becomes upright in the Portrait Top orientation.

[Picture of the launch[1](http://screencast.com/t/m0P32tPrj)

There has to be something about the project file that is causing this. Still searching.

Looking around I found [this[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797953/my-app-starts-upside-down) which states the order is important and the top most is the inital view. So now I am really puzzled as the Portrait Bottom is at the head of the list.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me too today. Easiest temporary fix is to look at your target's "Supported Device Orientations" on the "Summary" tab. My guess is that both "Portrait" and "Upside Down" are selected.

For some reason my XCode was defaulting to "Upside Down" and deselecting that orientation made the problem go away.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, I have tried almost everything (project setting, info plist, code level mast setting, app clean up, simulator reset) but no help. How to resolve that? My app is working perfectly for other orientations except upsidedown.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution!

Evidently there is a bug in Interface Builder. If you simply click off all the orientations, then click them back on in the desired order the Info.plist is built correctly.