# My app starts upside down

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation

An engine that I've worked on for a while and has shipped games is now launching my current project upside down and right away rotates the UIView the way it suppose to be. I create the interface with code and this is about how it looks like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    
    ...

    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]; 
    CGRect windowBounds = screenBounds; 
    windowBounds.origin.y = 0.0;
    UIWindow* win = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:windowBounds];  
    win.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    UIMyView* view = [[UIMyView alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds]; 
    UIMyViewController* controller = [[UIMyViewController alloc] init]; 
    controller.view = view; 

    view.multipleTouchEnabled = true;   
    view.windowWrapper = this;  
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [win addSubview:view];

    ...
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation;
{
    s32 validOrientations = ((cViewMM*)(self.view)).windowWrapper->GetValidOrientations();
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && (validOrientations & 0x01))
        return true;

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown && (validOrientations & 0x02))
        return true;

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft && (validOrientations & 0x04))
        return true;

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight && (validOrientations & 0x08))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

The problem occures only if I want to launch the application in UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft. Debugging through the application it looks like when I try to add my view to the window internally the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: is called multiple times. First with UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait which returns false then UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight which return true (since it's valid orientation) and then UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft which also returns true (since it's valid orientation and it's the current orientation of the device).

Oh and to be more specific this is happening only on iPhone not on iPad. They use the same code to setup this view.

What am I doing wrong?

-- EDIT --

OK I was wrong about the execution of shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: it is executed 3 times asking for UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait, 2 times for UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, then once for UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight, and again once UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft.

GameCenter is alreay initializing at this point and since it's pushing some extra UI I thought it may be it, but it wasn't.

Comment: 'What am I doing wrong?' Not standing on your head? =]

Comment: If it's gonna help I'll do it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check in your Info.plist that the array of supported orientations *starts* with portrait (right-side-up). If it starts with any different orientation your app will launch in that orientation.

Comment: Both UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight are in my plist and they are in this order. I want to support both just I want the initial orientation to be the orientation of the device.

Comment: Ah. Hmm... I don't have a solid answer for that. If you don't show the status bar then you can make your default image look like it is in portrait but that isn't a complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem and was sad to see it unanswered. Then I realized one key thing that proves this is just how things work: the Default.png startup image is upside down as well. There is nothing you can do in your app to fix that. You can choose which landscape mode starts correctly (home button on left or right) but you can't make them BOTH work.

Comment: Yes you are right about the default.png. It works just fine on iPad. I believe that this problem also doesn't exists on older iOS versions (I actually forgot it that's the case).

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution!

Evidently there is a bug in Interface Builder. If you simply click off all the orientations, then click them back on in the desired order the Info.plist is built correctly.

Comment: As I said all the interface is created with code I don't use Interface Builder for this project. And I don't think the issue is in Info.plist since there isn't a desired order. I want to support both orientations UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight. I just need the app to start in the orientation that the device is when launching the applicatiion.

Comment: The issue was not the application supporting the orientation, the issue is with the simulator itself starting upside down. I have chacked again and the simulator definitely is sensitive to the order in the plist.

Comment: I'm testing on iPhone not on emulator.

Comment: The upside down problem is also on the iOS devices. If the order is incorrect the launch picture and status bar will be upside down. In my case, my orientation code on both simulator and iOS device detects and corrects the view.

Comment: The upside down problem is also on the iOS devices. If the order is incorrect the launch picture and status bar will be upside down. In my case, my orientation code on both simulator and iOS device detects and corrects the view.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked as tgunr said BUT I had to remove from simulator folder the whole app, otherwise, the change in orientation didn't work.